# Skylanders Swapforce X box 360 RT

Tags: skylanders, skylanders-swap-force

My son reached a point on screen where his character needed to pull a lever (labelled RT) despite firing, jumping, changing character and doing just about anything we could think of, this handle will not let itself be pulled.  So after one hour's use on the x-box, we are dead in the water. Any help would be much appreciated.  He's only 6 and I haven't got a clue!

Comment: Well RT stands for Right Trigger (the large button on the back that looks literally like a trigger) and is pressed with the right index finger usually.

I've never played Skylanders nor do I know what context (level, situation, etc) the question is being asked with.  Have you tried Google?

Comment: Hopefully someone more versed in the ways of Skylanders can come in and help but if not, I'll try to look it up in a bit.